# Could not find method buildFeatures() for arguments [build_an2eirsndh84jivytk4d41bny$_run_closure2$_closure6@a7bddb6]

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Was trying to run old code on new environment and got this instead:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\diego\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\cloud_firestore-4.13.5\android\build.gradle' line: 55
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':cloud_firestore'.

> Could not find method buildFeatures() for arguments [build_an2eirsndh84jivytk4d41bny$_run_closure2$_closure6@a7bddb6] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 631ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Did you try 'flutter clean'?

Comment: I tried it now. When I run the app I get the same results